# How to set a specific rails layout to a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have the following controller for invitations provided by `devise_invitable`

```
class InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
 
  layout 'devise', only: [:edit]
  layout "admin", only: [:new]

  ..........code.........
end
```

In a nutshell, I want the code to display the `admin` layout on the `new` action and the `devise` default layout on `edit`. I'd expect for the above code to work but what I've found is that the last `layout` call that I make clobbers everything. The above snippet will render `admin` for all actions and when I switch them around then the `devise` layout will clobber everything. I don't understand why that is.

I'm [looking at this devise wiki here](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-custom-layouts) but I'm having no luck. What could I be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stolen from [this API page](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Layout/ClassMethods/layout)

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 layout :determine_layout
 def determine_layout
   if is_admin?
     "admin"
   else
     "application"
   end
...
end
```

Comment: So this did work and it showed me that I had to customize my rendering with other actions too. Thank you!